# Data processing in lists with duplicates in Python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have two lists: one contains the products and the other one contains their associated prices. The lists can contain an undefined number of products. An example of the lists would be something like:

- Products : ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'Pineapple', 'Pineapple']
- Prices: ['1.00', '2.00', '1.50', '3.00', '0.50', '1.50', '2.00', '1.00', '1.00']

I want to be able to remove all the duplicates from the products list and keep only the cheapest price associated with the unique products in the price list. Note that some products might have the same price (in our example the Pineapple).

The desired final lists would be something like:

- Products : ['Apple',  'Orange', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'Pineapple']
- Prices: ['1.00', '3.00', '0.50', '2.00', '1.00']

I would like to know the most effective way to do so in Python. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
products = ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'Pineapple', 'Pineapple']
prices = ['1.00', '2.00', '1.50', '3.00', '0.50', '1.50', '2.00', '1.00', '1.00']

min_prices = OrderedDict()
for prod, price in zip(products, prices):
    min_prices[prod] = min(float(price), min_prices.get(prod, float('inf')))

>>> print min_prices.keys(), min_prices.values()
['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'Pineapple'] [1.0, 3.0, 0.5, 2.0, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way is to take advantage of dictionaries' enforcement of unique keys:

```
from operator import itemgetter
Products = ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'Pineapple', 'Pineapple']
Prices = ['1.00', '2.00', '1.50', '3.00', '0.50', '1.50', '2.00', '1.00', '1.00']

final = dict(sorted(zip(Products, Prices), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
```

Comment: One-line programming gone too far.

Comment: I don't think so; this is relatively simple.  If you prefer, you can break it up into multiple lines stored in variables, but ultimately it's still simpler than creating a function or using a `for` loop or anythign like that

Comment: I disagree, your way requires the reader to be familiar with dict, zip, sorted, its key and reverse optional arguments, and itemgetter. While the other answer uses about as many standard library symbols, they are mostly from the core 20 most used, whereas itemgetter is probably not in the top 100. Less characters != more readable.

Comment: @morningstar You don't have to make all your python code extremely easy to read for beginners, this code is perfectly fine and readable. The only thing I have against it is the `O(N log N)` runtime

Comment: @jamylak agreed on inefficiency.  For a short list, thought it would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
prices = map(float,prices)
r={}
for k,v in zip(products,prices):
    if v < r.setdefault(k,float('inf')):
        r[k] = v
products,prices = r.keys(),map(str,r.values())
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `sys.maxint` use `float('inf')`

Answer (score 0):

Not the shortest solution, but it illustrates the point: Suppose that your lists are `products` and `prices`, respectively. Then:

```
lookup = dict()    
for prod, price in zip(products, prices):
    if prod not in lookup:
        lookup[prod] = price
    else:
        lookup[prod] = min(price, lookup[prod])
```

At this point, the `lookup` dict contains each of your products, and its minimal price. A dict is certainly a better data structure for this than two lists; if you *really* want to have this as two separate lists instead, you can do something like this:

```
new_prods = []
new_prices = []
for prod, price in lookup.items():
    new_prods.append(prod)
    new_prices.append(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> products = ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'Pineapple', 'Pineapple']
>>> prices =  ['1.00', '2.00', '1.50', '3.00', '0.50', '1.50', '2.00', '1.00', '1.00']
>>> dic = OrderedDict()
>>> for x,y in zip(products,prices):
...     dic.setdefault(x, []).append(y)
...     
>>> dic.keys()
['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'Pineapple']
>>> [min(val, key = float) for val in dic.values()]
['1.00', '3.00', '0.50', '2.00', '1.00']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to do this:

```
Products = ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'Pineapple', 'Pineapple']
Prices = ['1.00', '2.00', '1.50', '3.00', '0.50', '1.50', '2.00', '1.00', '1.00']

Prices=[float(price) for price in Prices]

di={}
for prod,price in zip(Products,Prices):
    di.setdefault(prod,[]).append(price)

for key,val in di.items():
    di[key]=min(val)

print di
```

Prints `{'Orange': 3.0, 'Pineapple': 1.0, 'Apple': 1.0, 'Peach': 2.0, 'Banana': 0.5}`

If you want two lists in the same order, you can do this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

new_prod=OrderedDict.fromkeys(Products).keys()
new_prices=[di[item] for item in new_prod]
```

Prints:

```
['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Peach', 'Pineapple']
[1.0, 3.0, 0.5, 2.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: your `uniq` function is outdated, nowadays the idiom is `OrderedDict.fromkeys(seq).keys()` which doesn't utilize the `not seen_add(x)` hack